Crucial X6 500GB SSD very slow
The external Crucial X6 500GB SSD CT500X6SSD9 is very slow. The ejection process takes a very long time, read and write speeds drop below 20 MiB/s. I have created a conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/:
options usb-storage quirks=0634:5602:u

I used the command
sudo update-initramfs -u

I reset but dmesg shows:
[   27.417748] usb 2-3.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   27.433252] usb 2-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0634, idProduct=5602, bcdDevice= 1.10
[   27.433254] usb 2-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   27.433255] usb 2-3.1: Product: CT500X6SSD9
[   27.433256] usb 2-3.1: Manufacturer: Micron
[   27.433257] usb 2-3.1: SerialNumber: 2238E4992D35
[   27.469289] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   27.498550] scsi host6: uas
[   27.498655] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   27.984500] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Micron   CT500X6SSD9      PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6 

Blacklist UAS is ignored? Any idea what to do with this drive?
sudo smartctl --all -d scsi /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Micron
Product:              CT500X6SSD9
Revision:             PMAP
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        500 107 862 016 bytes [500 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is fully provisioned [LBPRZ=1]
Logical Unit id:      0x500014a000000001
Serial number:        2238E4992D35
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sat Sep  7 10:18:06 2024 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging


Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-41-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 12 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11600 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7D18
System Version: 1.0


You can check if your drive is still in a healthy state with smartmontools.
So proceed with the following steps:

Install smartmontools with
sudo apt install smartmontools


Acquire your recognized device name with
fdisk -l

and remember its name. Or use a similar tool that outputs your device path like /dev/sda(used in the following examples) or /dev/nvme0n1 or something similar.

Use that device path as input to smartctl (a binary from smartmontools):
sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda

This runs a short test on your drive

Wait for some minutes (a rough estimation is printed after executing the command above).

Get the results with
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda



If you followed those steps, you will get an output with lines like
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   049    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
...
...

and
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13182         -

Interpreting these data is not easy and above the scope of this answer, but you surely should look out for FAIL or other ERROR messages (PRE-FAIL and OLD_AGE are not that critical; they occur regularly). The interpretation of these values varies.
Now you could estimate the health status of your drive. Given the info of your question, there surely will be something wrong.

I added SMART data in the question. I had to specify the type of -d scsi, SMART Health Status: OK

I didn't expect this ;-/ The S.M.A.R.T. support of your drive seems to be very limited.
